# Equation subnumbers in IEEEtrantools?

Tags: equations, ieeetran

I'm using subnumbers in IEEEtrantools:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

Numbered equation:

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  a & = & b \;.
  \label{eq:tTy}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}


Subnumbered equations:

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rrCll}
  & c & = & 3d & \IEEEyessubnumber
  \\*[-0.625\normalbaselineskip]
  \smash{\left\{\IEEEstrut[6\jot]\right.} \label{eq:NvY} &&&& \nonumber \;. % the invisible row
  \\*[-0.625\normalbaselineskip]
  & e & = & f & \IEEEyessubnumber
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

Next equation:

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  h & = & i \;.
  \label{eq:tog}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

It gives:

[image]

I want subnumbers to be independed of the previous and next equations. So I need to get this:

[image]

How can I get it? (IEEEtrantools is the package I'd like to stick to.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer by Adobe does solve the problem to some extent but is not quite effective. Especially when one sub numbering follows another, only the equation counter is incremented but the internal sub-counter is not incremented.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

Numbered equation:

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
 a & = & b \;.
\label{eq:tTy}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}


Subnumbered equations:
\addtocounter{equation}{1}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rrCll}
& c & = & 3d & \IEEEyessubnumber
\\*[-0.625\normalbaselineskip]
\smash{\left\{\IEEEstrut[6\jot]\right.} \label{eq:NvY} &&&& \nonumber \;. % the invisible row
\\*[-0.625\normalbaselineskip]
& e & = & f & \IEEEyessubnumber
\end{IEEEeqnarray}`

Next equation:
\addtocounter{equation}{1}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
h & = & i \; \IEEEyessubnumber
\label{eq:tog}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}.
```

[image: This outputs...]

This problem can be solved by introducing **\IEEEyesnumber** command just before the **\IEEEyessubnumber** and that would make the current IEEEeqnarray independent of the previous and next equations, and would also increment the equation counter and start sub-counter afresh.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

Numbered equation:

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
 a & = & b \;.
\label{eq:tTy}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}


Subnumbered equations:

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rrCll}
& c & = & 3d &  \IEEEyesnumber \IEEEyessubnumber
\\*[-0.625\normalbaselineskip]
\smash{\left\{\IEEEstrut[6\jot]\right.} \label{eq:NvY} &&&& \nonumber \;. % the invisible row
\\*[-0.625\normalbaselineskip]
& e & = & f & \IEEEyessubnumber
\end{IEEEeqnarray}`

Next equation:
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
h & = & i \; \IEEEyesnumber \IEEEyessubnumber
\label{eq:tog}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Moreover, manually incrementing counters makes code really really tough to debug!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is indeed the best way to work around the buggy subnumbering mechanism here.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I solved it: one needs to add 1 to counter before the subnumbered equation:

```
\addtocounter{equation}{1}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rrCll}
  & c & = & 3d & \IEEEyessubnumber
  \\*[-0.625\normalbaselineskip]
  \smash{\left\{\IEEEstrut[6\jot]\right.} \label{eq:NvY} &&&& \nonumber \;. % the invisible row
  \\*[-0.625\normalbaselineskip]
  & e & = & f & \IEEEyessubnumber
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```